# Instance returned by Session.BeginTransaction() equals to Session.Transaction?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a question about transaction on NHibernate. As far as i know there are two ways to retrieve `ITransaction` from `ISession`.

**Option 1**

```
ISession.BeginTransaction();
```

**Option 2**

```
ISession.Transaction;
```

If i execute them consecutively like this

```
ITransaction trans = session.BeginTransaction();
ITransaction trans2 = session.Transaction;
```

Is `trans` equal `trans2` ?

Comment: beginTransaction as it states begins a transaction, while session.Transaction will return the current active transaction if null will create one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate source @ https://github.com/nhibernate

from session implementation of Isession @ NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl

```
public ITransaction BeginTransaction()
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        if (rootSession != null)
        {
            // Todo : should seriously consider not allowing a txn to begin from a child session
            //      can always route the request to the root session...
            log.Warn("Transaction started on non-root session");
        }

        CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus();
        return connectionManager.BeginTransaction();
    }
}

public ITransaction Transaction
{
    get { return connectionManager.Transaction; }
}
```

from NHibernate.Adonet.ConnectionManager class

```
public ITransaction BeginTransaction()
{
    Transaction.Begin();
    return transaction;
}

public ITransaction Transaction
{
     get
     {
         if (transaction == null)
         {
              transaction = session.Factory.TransactionFactory.CreateTransaction(session);
         }

         return transaction;
     }
}
```

Comment: Based on the implementation. It will be the same instance. Thanks kalki!